# You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: apache2, osx-snow-leopard, joomla1.5

I got Apache2/PHP/MySQL running fine on my Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

I am able to access "http://localhost" and am also able to access "http://localhost/~username/". I also tried copying a small HTML website into both these locations (i.e. /Library/WebServer/Documents & /Users/username/Sites) and it works perfectly in both cases.

Now when I unzipped my Joomla download to a directory Joomla15 and copied it into /Library/WebServer/Documents OR /Users/username/Sites, and tried to access "http://localhost/Joomla15" OR "http://localhost/~username/Joomla15" respectively, I get following message:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /Joomla15 on this server.

Where have i gone wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You might have better luck over at http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the permissions of your files with chmod.